# How to put all objects of a class into a list

Tags: python

I want to make a list of all the names that are given in a class this is the code right now I’m getting the error that is none type I feel like the append isn’t working

```
class Names:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
        self._list_name= []
    def make_list(self,name):
       self._list_name.append(name)
    def __str__(self):
        for i in self._list_name:
            return i
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: The loop returns on the first iteration, it won't return all the names in the list. Try `return ','.join(self._list_name)` to return a comma-separated list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't return inside the loop. That will just return the first name in the list. And if you call `__str__()` before you call `make_list()`, there won't be anything in the list. The loop won't run and the method will return `None`, which is invalid for the `__str__()` method.

Instead, concatenate all the names into a string.

```
class Names:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
        self._list_name= []
    def make_list(self,name):
       self._list_name.append(name)
    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(self._list_name)
```

BTW, the name `make_list` doesn't really describe what that method does. It doesn't make a list, it adds to the list. Call it something like `add_name()`.

I don't know how you plan on using this, but you might want to include the initial name in the list, so change

```
self._list_name = []
```

to

```
self._list_name = [name]
```